# PHP Fastest search algorithm for two dimensional array

Tags: php, algorithm, search

I am working on a data import process and need to search different 2 dimensional arrays for a specific code. The array structure look like this:

```
Index ID   Code
----------------
0     34    P1
1     5     AR
2     71    Y2
3     677   UI
4     14    IO
...
```

In import file I have **Code** for which I get their **ID** from dataset array (above). I need to know what is the best algorithm to get ID through code very fast. Currently I am doing something like this to get IDs:

```
foreach ($dataset as $row) {
   if ($row['Code'] == $code) {
       return $row['ID'];
   }
}
```

Note: The dataset arrays are sorted in Ascending order by **Code** when fetched from database.

The binary search algorithm might have worked if the code was an integer. In current scenario it is alpha-numeric, so we have to search for another algorithm.

Comment: _best algorithm_ questions are better suited to SO's sister site http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How large will your dataset be?

Comment: @toby-allen Total 9 Datasets in memory having 75,3400,264,6090,99,1258,87,120,300 records. Note that I hold only ID and Code columns in array

Comment: ohhh phew for a second I thought that was one number.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, instead of searching in array its better to search while fetching from db.

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `Code` = '".$code."'"
```

Because if your table has too many records then it will fetch only required one.

Comment: No that was worst, previously the structure was like that. The insert query contained sub-queries (select) statements that fetched data from other tables. Now after loading the master datasets in memory had increased the overall import speed to 15 times the previous one. Note that the quantity of master recordset is feasible  to be stored in available memory.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is already sorted by `Code` then the fastest way will certainly be to binary search on `Code`, giving `O(log n)` average performance.

[This link](http://terenceyim.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/all-purpose-binary-search-in-php/) provides some code for performing binary searches over PHP arrays that you can adapt to your purposes.

Comment: is there any php function for this algorithm. It would be better if you can post some code based on the above structure.

Comment: @asim-ishaq is the data sorted by `Code`? Because if it is not, then a binary search won't work.

Comment: @Gian Yes it is, the dataset in the question is just a sample orginally it is sorted.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, the question says "Note: The dataset arrays are sorted in Ascending order by Code when fetched from database."

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to some PHP binary search code.

Comment: @Gian I know, I saw it. The comment was for OP. OP appeared to not know what a binary search was and so I was making sure they knew that it had to be sorted to work as the sample data provided is not.

Comment: @Gian I have gone through the binary alogorithm but it appears that it can work only if the code is an integer. In current scenario it is alpha-numeric. What do you day?

Comment: A binary search is going to work for any type of values for which the comparison operators work (e.g., <, <=, >, >=).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you perform this search many times? In such case the fastest algorithm will be to use a hash. First copy your data (this happens only once) to an, making codes into keys. This is sort of costly, but only happens once:

```
foreach ($rows as $r) {
   $indexedData[$r['Code']] = $id;
}
```

And then the search becomes a single lookup:

```
function findIdByCode($code) {
   global $indexedData;
   return $indexedData[$code];
}
```